# Is it possible to build and run to both device and simulator simultaneously?

Tags: xcode, xcode7.3

I wonder if XCode can build and run to both device and simulator simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible only, if there will be 2 different xcode is running simultaneously otherwise its would't allowed to test both things simultaneously in device and simulator.